# Opentok annotation using angular 2

Tags: angular, html5-canvas, opentok

I am using opentok for video feeding in my application.

Please provide some reference of using **annotations** on opentok using angular 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to do screen sharing with annotation, or do you just want to annotate over video feeds?  Have you looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentok-annotation?

Comment: I want to annotate over video feeds..

Comment: There is a sample app showing how to do this here: https://github.com/opentok/one-to-one-screen-annotations-sample-apps/tree/master/JS/sample-app

It's not angular specific, but it shouldn't make much of a difference.